Mongoose TTL expiring even when condition is false
I have this mongoose Schema, I would like to the model delete itself after 60 seconds if the field paid is false.
However when using TTL the document expires even if the field paid is true.
I've even tried to create a TTL inside the schema but with no success. What should I do?
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const donationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    ngo: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'Ngo', required: true },
    type: { type: String, default: 'ads', required: true },
    amount: { type: Number },
    iat: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    paid: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    orderID: { type: String },
});

donationSchema.index(
    { createdAt: 1 },
    {
        expireAfterSeconds: 60,
        partialFilterExpression: { paid: false },
    },
);

function autoPopulateChildren(next) {
    this.populate('user', 'fullName level avatar country -_id');
    next();
}

donationSchema.pre('find', autoPopulateChildren);

module.exports = new mongoose.model('Donation', donationSchema);


Did you forget to include the field createdAt in your schema? The TTL index may not be able to remove the document if you do not include the field.

Be aware, the background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds. As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the period between the expiration of the document and the running of the background task. You cannot rely that documents are deleted exactly after 60 seconds, they may remain longer.

I've tried with the createAt field, however the document is deleted even if the field paid is true


Connect to your database with Compass and click on the Indexes tab. You may need to hit the little refresh button near the top left of the application.
Delete the Partial / TTL index that you set up.
Now that you have a clear slate you need to understand what's happening when you create a TTL index. MongoDB will add an index to any document in the donations collection that matches the partialFilterExpression option. It does this to save space as there is no need to add an index if paid: true. Now that MongoDB has an efficient way to search your documents, a background task runs every 60 seconds and if you have a TTL index on the donations collection it will calculate if the createdAt field is less than the current time minus the expireAfterSeconds value. If it is, the document will be deleted.
You need a createdAt field in your schema so that the TTL background task knows to delete your document. The easist way to do that is to use the timestamps: true option which will automatically add a createdAt and updatedAt field in all new documents. It would look like so:

const donationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   user: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   ngo: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'Ngo', required: true },
   type: { type: String, default: 'ads', required: true },
   amount: { type: Number },
   iat: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
   paid: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
   },
   orderID: { type: String },
},{ timestamps: true }); //< Add this option


Keep your index the way you have written it:

donationSchema.index(
   { createdAt: 1 },
   {
      expireAfterSeconds: 60,
      partialFilterExpression: { paid: false },
   },
);


Restart your server. If you navigate back to Compass and refresh. You will see the Partial / TTL index has been recreated.
Create a new document and wait a minute or so. If the document you created had paid: false then it will be automatically deleted.
If you create a document with paid: true it will not have the index added. If you then update the document with paid: false the index will be added and that document will become a candidate for deletion.

